# Error on 'Param' object is not callable - Apache Spark for Recommendation System

Tags: pyspark, recommendation-engine

I am using apache spark for recommendation system. On the part of evaluation, to find the precision and recall, I got the error.

The code as stated below

---

```
def print_metrics(predictions_and_labels):
    metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictions_and_labels)
    print('Precision of True ', metrics.precision(1))
    print('Precision of False', metrics.precision(0))
    print('Recall of True    ', metrics.recall(1))
    print('Recall of False   ', metrics.recall(0))
    print('F-1 Score         ', metrics.fMeasure())
    print('Confusion Matrix\n', metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray())

predictions = model.transform(testRatings)
accuracy = model.predictionCol().evaluate(predictions)
print('F1 Accuracy: %f' % accuracy)

predictions_and_labels = predictions.select("prediction", "foreclosure_status").rdd \
.map(lambda r: (float(r[0]), float(r[1])))

print_metrics(predictions_and_labels)
```

---

And the error I got mention that

> "'Param' object is not callable".

Please could anyone suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.